# Empty message and actual message MQ client issue

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq

I am sending a message from one queue to another queue, for example when in my input queue, if there is an empty message , then an actual message, when the code starts queuing, it doesn't send me the actual message once it sees the first empty message.

```
Import queue:

     -> empty message
Test -> actual message
```

This is the piece of message am getting and sending.

```
if (mqMsg.MessageLength > 0 && mqMsg.DataLength > 0)
{
messageData = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);
}
```

putting

```
mqQueue.Put(mqMsg, mqPutMsgOpts);
```

this is how am implementing:

```
while(if any message is available)
{
  //go a read/get
  mqMsg = new MQMessage();
  mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();
  mqQueue.Get(mqMsg);
  if (mqMsg.MessageLength > 0 && mqMsg.DataLength > 0)
  {
   //posted to send method
  }    
}
```

another method(send) - sends it.

```
 mqPutMsgOpts = new MQPutMessageOptions();
 mqQueue.Put(mqMsg, mqPutMsgOpts);
```

How do i process this so that, the queue continues to send messages even when there is empty message ?

Comment: `Perhaps you should employ an `Else` block in your code.. with `Reputation points higher than 1` one would think that you understand how to construct a basic conditional statement [MSDN if Else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of a loop? Like `while` loop? I cannot get where is the problem.

Comment: I have not quite understood what the problem here. Can you please provide some clarity? What do you mean by empty message? a message with no data/body?

Comment: @Shashi - Yes, its with no data/body. ie. data length is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checking for MessageLength is enough.

```
if(mqMsg.MessageLength > 0)
{
     // Send message to another queue.
}
```

But it's important to understand why there is a message with no body and fix that problem. Why would someone send a message that has no body?